# jQuery, Animate height from a variable value to auto on div

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate, toggle

I want to animate the height of a div from a variable value to auto with the toggle animation. I know I'm not calling my variable properly. Just trying to see how to do this.

```
var scheight = $('.searchcontainer').height();
$('.searchcontainer').toggle(
    function () {
        $(".searchcontainer").animate({ height: scheight + "px" }, 500);
    },
    function () {
        $(".searchcontainer").animate({ height: auto}, 500);
    }
);
```

Comment: Use `css` instead of `animate`

Comment: `.animate` requires a fixed `height` in `px`. It cannot take a value `auto` and animate. You should use `.css` also it should be `{ height: 'auto'}` (note the quotes around auto) >> http://jsfiddle.net/skram/yAADY/ <<

Comment: You mean something like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/xGUR5/?

Comment: Something like that I have dynamic content that changes the height so I want it to animate to the height when the dynamic content changes.

Answer (score 0):

It will be easier to animate both ways if you place another container for your content within the "searchcontainer" element. This approach will let you detect the height of your content, and having that pixel value (instead of relying on 'auto') gives you a target that you can now animate to:

http://jsfiddle.net/XdPry/3/

**html:**

```
<div style="height:200px;border:1px solid #000000">
    <div class="searchcontainer" style="background-color:#aa22aa">
        <div>content</div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

**jquery:**

```
$('.searchcontainer:first').toggle(
    function () {
        $(this).animate({ height: parseInt($(this).parent('div').height()) }, 500);
    },
    function () {
        $(this).animate({ height: parseInt($(this).children('div:first').height()) }, 500);
    }
);​
```